# Polymer Neon-Animation multiple finish listeners

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm writing a Polymer element that implements the [Neon Animation](https://github.com/PolymerElements/neon-animation) element library. I'm implementing the `NeonAnimationRunnerBehavior` behavior for my element. This element in particular has multiple animations (that run fine) which need to call unique ending functions when each animation ends.

The documentation suggests using listeners like this:

```
listeners: {
    // this event is fired when the animation finishes
    "neon-animation-finish": "imageFadeOutComplete"
},
```

This works great if you have one animation callback. But I have an animation for hovering, leaving hover state, and clicking (tapping) my element. I've tried exploring the `neon-animation-finish` event, but it seems to be identical for each animation.

So, my question is: Is it possible to have each animation call a different function when it completes?

I was hoping it would be something like:

```
....

animationConfig: {
    value: function() {
        return {
            "imageFadeOut": {
                name: "fade-out-animation",
                node: this.$.image,
                complete: "imageFadeOutComplete"
            },
...
```

But, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`playAnimation` accepts a second argument that will be passed as the detail to the `neon-animation-finish` event handler, so you could do something like this:

```
animateFadeIn: function() {
  this.playAnimation('imageFadeIn', 'imageFadeIn');
},

animateFadeOut: function() {
  this.playAnimation('imageFadeOut', 'imageFadeOut');
},

_animationFinish: function(e, animation) {
  switch(animation) {
    case 'imageFadeOut':
      ...
      break;
    case 'imageFadeIn':
      ...
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I saw that it took two arguments, but wasn't sure how to implement it. This should work.

Comment: The second argument can be of any type. I'm passing a function that the event handler then calls.